# How can I rotate a CATextLayer properly in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, catransform3d, catextlayer

I'm currently facing an issue that when rotating a CATextLayer the frame size would be transformed unexpectedly at the same time. I expect the text can be rotated at some angle **without changing its frame size**. If anyone could enlighten me about this, thanks in advance.

What I have tried:

```
var someAngle: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        drawText()
    }
}

func drawText() {

    for layer in someView.layer.sublayers ?? [] where layer is CATextLayer {
        layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }

    let textLayer = CATextLayer()
    textLayer.fontSize = 26
    textLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    textLayer.string = "Hello world"
    textLayer.alignmentMode = .center

    textLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    textLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(someAngle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

    let textSize = calculateTextSize(text: "Hello world", font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 26))
    let origin = CGPoint(x: someView.bounds.midX - textSize.width/2, y: someView.bounds.midY - textSize.height/2)
    textLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: textSize)

    someView.layer.addSublayer(textLayer)
}
```

However, the result looks like this:

[image]

**And my expectation is similar to this:**
[image]

Comment: Where do you have a shapeLayer? You are only setting background color to the textLayer alone, right?

Comment: Exactly. There is no shapeLayer, I only set the background color. But as you see, the textLayer frame changed a lot when updating its rotation angle.

Comment: That's because you have applied transform to the layer itself.  There is no way to get background alone not transformed. You may need to have another layer for shape.

Comment: “the frame size would be transformed unexpectedly at the same time”. It’s not unexpected. Well, maybe you didn’t expect it. But the notion of frame loses its meaning when a transform is applied; it cannot be used for anything. It signifies only the bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

solved this by adding a textLayer property outside the function.

```
var textLayer = CATextLayer()
```

Comment: I have the problem you have but it's not clear what you mean by this answer? Where did you add that text layer?